# Length in meters arcobjects

Tags: arcobjects, polyline-creation, length

i have a an array of polylines in epsg:3857 projection, and i want to calculate length of each polyline. i am new to arcgis and arcobjects, i couldn't find the functions that i need.

Should i use IGeometryServer2.GetLengths2 or something else?

note: if it matters i am developing a server object extension on C#

another note: if i need to use IGeometryServer2.GetLengths2 what should i use for IlinearUnit parameter?

Edit:

Administrator marked question as possible duplicate but this link
[Programmatically calculating the length of all polyline features in a featureclass](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12501/programmatically-calculating-the-length-of-all-polyline-features-in-a-featurecla)
shows calculating length in map units not in meters

this is the code i am currently using but i think it doesn't correctly calculates length

```
IProjectedCoordinateSystem myCoordSys = (IProjectedCoordinateSystem)myGeom.SpatialReference;

ILinearUnit myLinUnit = myCoordSys.CoordinateUnit;
IPolylineArray ploughList = new PolylineArrayClass();


ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPointCollection4 eachPloughPointColl = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PolylineClass();

ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.WKSPoint[] aWKSPointBuffer = new ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.WKSPoint[2];
WKSPoint ploughStartPoint = new WKSPoint();
WKSPoint ploughEndPoint = new WKSPoint();
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IGeometryBridge2 pGeoBrg = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.GeometryEnvironment() as IGeometryBridge2;

//create lines
for (int j = 0; j < ploughCount; j++)
{
    //check point collection - clear
    if(eachPloughPointColl.PointCount > 0)
        eachPloughPointColl.RemovePoints(0, eachPloughPointColl.PointCount);

    //compute point coords for plough line
    ploughStartPoint.X = myGeom.Envelope.XMin;
    ploughStartPoint.Y = myGeom.Envelope.YMax - myFieldList[i].ploughWidth * (j + 1);

    ploughEndPoint.X = myGeom.Envelope.XMax;
    ploughEndPoint.Y = ploughStartPoint.Y;

    aWKSPointBuffer[0] = ploughStartPoint;
    aWKSPointBuffer[1] = ploughEndPoint;

    //set points into point collection
    pGeoBrg.SetWKSPoints(eachPloughPointColl, ref aWKSPointBuffer);

    //cast to polyline
    IPolyline4 bigPloughLine = (IPolyline4)eachPloughPointColl;

    ITopologicalOperator myTopo = (ITopologicalOperator)bigPloughLine;

    IPolyline4 finalPloughLine = (IPolyline4) myTopo.Intersect(myGeom, esriGeometryDimension.esriGeometry1Dimension);





    //rotate back to original position -- unnecessary remove!!! REMOVE!!!!!!
    rotationCNT = (ITransform2D)finalPloughLine;
    rotationCNT.Rotate(geomOrigin, Math.PI * 2 - myFieldList[i].ploughDirection.Angle);



    //add plough line to array
    ploughList.Add(finalPloughLine);
}
IGeometryServer2 myGeomS = new GeometryServerImplClass();

IDoubleArray myLengthList = myGeomS.GetLengths2(myGeom.SpatialReference, ploughList, myLinUnit);
```

I am trying to draw lines on a polygon and calculating it's lengths
like this post
[Filling a polygon with lines using Postgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24064/filling-a-polygon-with-lines-using-postgis)

But I think I can't get lengths correct.

Comment: This question is similar to yours, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12501/programmatically-calculating-the-length-of-all-polyline-features-in-a-featurecla